# Query to identify records without certain values

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table of data that looks something like this:

```
ID Num | Code
-------------
   1   |   A
   1   |   B
   1   |   C
   1   |   D
   2   |   A
   2   |   B
   3   |   A
   3   |   B
   3   |   D
   4   |   B
   5   |   A
   5   |   B
   5   |   E
```

And I need to be able to write an SQL query to show me all ID Numbers that do not have Codes C or D associated with them. (Which in this example would be ID Numbers 2, 4, & 5.)

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: I'm sorry. It's DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use NOT IN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_Num
FROM t
WHERE ID_Num NOT IN
(SELECT ID_Num
 FROM t
 WHERE code = 'C'
 OR code = 'D')
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to approach this type of question using `group by` and `having`:

```
select id_num
from t
group by id_num
having sum(case when code in ('C', 'D') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'not exists' (often more performant of not in)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_Num
FROM yourtable f1
WHERE not exists
(
    SELECT * FROM yourtable f2 
    WHERE f2.code in ('C', 'D') and f2.ID_Num=f1.ID_Num
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'left outer join lateral' and take not founded row like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f1.ID_Num
FROM yourtable f1
LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL 
(
    SELECT f2.ID_Num FROM yourtable f2
    WHERE f2.code in ('C', 'D') AND f2.ID_Num=f1.ID_Num
    FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY
) f3 on 1=1
WHERE f3.ID_Num is null
```